# How can I use Freemarker to show the List<Map<String,Object>> data?

Tags: java, freemarker

I put two `Map` objects in an `ArrayList`, and I want to show the different data based on the index of the arraylist, the java code is as follows:

```
List<Map<String, Object>> value = new ArrayList<Map<String, Object>>();
value.add(originalUnitProps);
value.add(nowUnitProps);
```

And the following is my template file:

```freemarker
<#list value as ori>
    <#if ori_index == 0>

        original info：<br/>

        <#list ori?keys as key>
            ${key}:${ori[key]}  <br/>
        </#list>
    <#else>
        <br/>
        now info：<br/>
        <#list ori?keys as key>
            ${key}:${ori[key]}  <br/>
        </#list>
    </#if>
</#list>
```

But it causes an exception:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: freemarker.template.DefaultObjectWrapper could not convert java.util.ArrayList to a TemplateHashModel.

Answer (score 3):

The problem has nothing to do with your template. Apparently, you have passed `value` to FreeMarker as the data-model, but the data-model must be a `Map<String, ...>` or a `TemplateHashModel`. So create a `Map<String, Object> dataModel`, put that `ArrayList` into that with a meaningful name, something like `dataModel.put("infos", value)`, pass the `dataModel` to FreeMarker instead of `value`, and then in the template use `<#list infos as ...>`.

Also, if you have an error message, next time attach the whole stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this to run successfully, setting up the model with this code:

```
Map<String, Object> originalUnitProps = new HashMap<>();
originalUnitProps.put("Lang1", Locale.FRENCH);
originalUnitProps.put("Lang2", Locale.CANADA_FRENCH);

Map<String, Object> nowUnitProps = new HashMap<>();
nowUnitProps.put("Lang3", Locale.ENGLISH);
nowUnitProps.put("Lang4", Locale.GERMAN);

List<Map<String, Object>> value = new ArrayList<Map<String, Object>>();
value.add(originalUnitProps);
value.add(nowUnitProps);

model.put("value", value);
```